Python nested loops over 2 lists in incorrect order in streamlit app
I have a list of messy strings describing the same street address. I want to extract one street name out of the list with regular expressions. I have another list that is ordered according to my preference of which messy pattern of "street" (e.g. str., Street etc.) is supposed to be selected out of the list.
My code is the following. Somehow the preference functions incorrectly.
The input list is generated by a streamlit multiselect box:
[
0:
"Ammerländer Heerstrasse"
1:
"Old. Ammerländer-Heerstr."
]

    default_street = None

    inputvalues = [
        (r"str\.",r"[öäüßA-za-z\-]*str\.",r"str\.","straße"),
        (r"straße",r"[öäüßA-za-z\-]*straße",'',''),
        (r"strasse",r"[öäüßA-za-z\-]*strasse",r"strasse","straße"),
        ...more markers of street names in German...
        ]

    # gasse                          

    while default_street == None:
        for match, str, streettorep, streetrep in inputvalues:
            for row in col2selectlist:
                if re.search(match, row) != None:
                    default_str = re.search(str, row)
                    default_street = re.sub(streettorep,streetrep,default_str.group())
        else:
            break

I would expect the result of default_street to be "Ammerländer-Heerstraße" from list item 1, since str. comes before strasse in my list, but the result is "Heerstraße" from list item 0. The result is the same if I reverse the list.
How can I get my preference list to work correctly?

col2selectlist isn't defined, and your "input list is generated by a streamlit multiselect box" isn't a valid Python list (if that is what is supposed to be in col2selectlist).

while default_street == None:
    for match, str, streettorep, streetrep in inputvalues:
        for row in col2selectlist:
            if re.search(match, row) != None:
                default_str = re.search(str, row)
                default_street = re.sub(streettorep, streetrep, default_str.group())
                print(default_street)
    else:
        break

should prove enlightening and then you will be able to solve your issue :)
(It does match the expected thing first ... but then it keeps iterating over col2selectlist)
you should change to just
for match, str, streettorep, streetrep in inputvalues:
        for row in col2selectlist:
            if re.search(match, row) != None:
                default_str = re.search(str, row)
                default_street = re.sub(streettorep, streetrep, default_str.group())
                break

print(default_street)



It was enlightening! Thank you. However, with your posted code it still does not behave as it should. Once I order the "inputvalues" list in reverse, it works. Go figure, but at least it now does what I want it to. Thank you.
